# Script for separating implementation from headers in a .h file

Tags: c++, header

Sometimes, when working with small classes, it's a pain in the ass to separate the implementation in a .cpp file, so I put all the code in the header file (kids, don't do this).

However, eventually these classes grow big time and I have to make the separation that I didn't do in the beginning.

The fact is that this is a mechanic process that could be perfectly done by a script or something like that, and I'm **sure** someone out there has already thought of this.

So, do you know of any script that could get a .h file, with all the function bodies implemented, and then return a stripped .h file and a nicely filled .cpp file?

Comment: how do you deal with the fact that the implementation is replicated in each object file, doesn't it cause problems at linkage? And why is it such pain? In many IDEs (Eclipse and MSVC for sure) when you do "add class" command 2 files are created. if you have too many of them you can (should) break them into subdirectories for better manageability.

Comment: @davka I believe this is a hindsight is 20/20 situation. To save 5 minutes originally he may have hours of restructuring classes to do now. Unfortunately I don't know of any automated way to do this otherwise tedious task ;(

Comment: davka, that's not the point of the question. I have big classes divided in as many files as needed.

Comment: @davka: "doesn't it cause problems at linkage" - not as long as all the member functions are inline. That's most easily achieved by putting the function definition inside the class definition.

Comment: "eventually these classes grow big" - there's your problem. You don't necessarily have to follow the open/closed principle to the letter, but turning a small class into a big class over time is pretty much pursuing the opposite of it!

Comment: o_O looks like the initial purpose of the question is getting, well, lost.

Comment: @TheOme3ga: you're right. If I had an answer, I'd give it to you, possibly even before I made a lot of smart-alec comments. I don't have an answer, sorry.

Comment: turn your class into a class template if you can. that way you have a legitimate reason to put everything into the header ;) and that will maybe reduce the size of your class by allowing you to move some complexity to another class

Comment: @Steve: naturally I know about inline functions. I wondered if this was the situation here. With inline functions you **must** keep them in the .h, right? So there wouldn't be a question of splitting the file. And when you add the first not inline function to the class you create the .cpp file. So it seems that the situation in OP is different, and hence I wonder - what happens during the linkage?

Comment: @TheOm3ga: I know,  that's why it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @davka: you can always change whether a function is inline, though, when you move it to the .cpp file. Just make sure you recompile everything. Presumably that change is part of the job of the script that TheOm3ga wants. I don't think "when you add the first not inline function to the class you create the .cpp file" is right, since you decide whether a function is going to be inline on the basis of what file you want to define it in, not on any other grounds. So the cause is the other way - when you add the .cpp file, you make the functions you want to move into it non-inline.

Comment: @davka: but you're generally right, as long as TheOm3ga catches his "big classes" early enough, he can just start putting new functions into the .cpp file, and leaving old ones in the .h as long as he likes. From the sound of it, though, I think it's too late for that, I think he's decided that there's a problem with the class as it is now, and wants to move some of its functions from .h to .cpp

Answer (score 2):

I'm guilty of this as well - although I've never really thought about automating the split before, as there are usually related project and test files to touch.

The idea of automating this is interesting, though.  The most promising tool I see out there is this one:

http://os.inf.tu-dresden.de/~hohmuth/prj/preprocess/

Comment: I'll give it a try, although the extra markup is something I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

It may be more trouble than it is worth but with a programmer's editor such as Epsilon you can write a routine to do that and bind it to any key sequence you like. However, I now make the header up front and use the programmer's editor to jump between them, create the function headers, fill in the class names (from the file name) and generally make my life easier. There is an up-front investment in time though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Lzz](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Just in case that website goes down, please copy the content in your answer while also linking to the source. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki thanks for pointing this out to me. I did'nt copy the content, because I guess  it would be completely useless without the possibility to get the tool from the website. The only important information is the name of the tool, which one can search for, in case the website moves or goes down.

Comment: I stand corrected, I didn't notice there was a tool to be downloaded :)