# Dismembering c++ source from header file

Tags: c++, c++builder, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Script for separating implementation from headers in a .h file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329469/script-for-separating-implementation-from-headers-in-a-h-file)

I have a big header file which contains source, like this:

```
class test_class_t 
{
public:
    test_proc()
    {
        // source code
    }
}
```

Is there a tool to dismember c++ source from header file and give me two files like these:

//header:

```
class test_class_t 
{
public:
    void test_proc();
}
```

// source:

```
void test_class_t::test_proc()
{
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: These tools are called refactoring tools. Some IDEs can do that kind of thing.

Comment: Refactoring in RAD studio do only rename. are you sure?

Comment: "possible duplicate of ..." I saw it, that question has no suitable answer, "Preprocess" is on linux. I want fo Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, member functions defined in the class itself are inline, if you move them into a separately compiled file that changes. To do a change like what you are asking for is probably not just moving functions "out", but splitting the class into a visible interface and a hidden implementation. I'd be *very* suprised indeed if a tool can do so automatically.

Comment: Just a comment on that, it's the compiler that ultimately decides what's inline or not. `inline` is rather a recommendation than a specification.

Comment: Right, member functions defined in the class itself are inline. I think it is possible and no serious problem.