# Tool to automate C++ header/source separation

Tags: c++, interface, header

I find it extremely tiring that I have to update code in two places whenever I'm developing a C++ class. During development, it happens 100+ times (at least for each private method) that I change the declaration of a method, add a `const` here or there, remove a `&` reference and so on. I literally hate it that I have to open a second file (the header file) every time I do a little change, and I've seen myself trying to avoid doing private interface changes in the middle of development just because I want to avoid this pain. (You probably think I'm lazy. I am, but it's also a REAL pain that stops me from being as productive as I could be.)

Usually, **all** of my declarations are in the header, and **all** of the definitions are in the source. I don't care about inlining or clever little optimization tricks. I love many things about C++, but I'd love it even more if refactoring and developing interfaces was as straightforward as in Java.

Are there any hints for dealing with the situation?

Comment: I have also started to loathe some of stack overflow because no matter what question you type, if it's not a dumb-ass question with an obvious answer that every experienced programmer could find out on his own, but instead a somewhat more general question that is still clearly defined, there is going to be a close request in <5 minutes.

Comment: I know that [Codelite](http://codelite.org/) IDE may synchronize signatures.

Comment: I'd actually love to see a statistic on how many new questions are not marked as duplicate or close requested.

Comment: @Hinton If you are able to precisely describe the "new" question, I guess you can produce such statistic yourself: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: @Hinton you should take that discussion to [the Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: `I literally hate it that I have to open a second file (the header file) every time I do a little change` You shouldn't be doing lots of little changes. You should have spent a great deal of time coming up with an interface for your classes, then _freezing that interface_. It should be quite rare to have to alter it, adding reference types or "adding a `const` here and there". That's a failing in your design and development process, not in the language.

Comment: You could probably do it with an emacs macro...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's true for the public interface, but not the private one. During development, I'm free to change the private interface as often as I like. According to every rule. And even if I didn't care about clean interfacing rules, the question remains the same.

Comment: When I work on small C++ projects without much prior design, I tend to keep both declaration and definition in the same cpp file, then split a header when ready. Otherwise, yes, you should design interface before. Also remember that this is not Java, so you are not forced to put every function in the class. You can make helpers `static` and keep them in the definition (cpp) part.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "You should have spent a great deal of time coming up with an interface for your classes, then freezing that interface." That depends on the stage of your project (for example what Hinton said above). BDUF is a thing that mostly never works well. You usually freeze your interface after doing lots of little changes.

Comment: Besides, I don't know about Eclipse, but Netbeans C++ can update header automatically if you refactor a method signature in cpp and viceversa (although the latter is tricky).

Comment: @BartoszKP: Well, yeah, but that stage shouldn't be protracted. I can't imagine this being an annoyance for more than a few days

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Probably we're talking about different kinds of software. In the context of an utility library you have an idea for and you're developing you may be right. In the context of a software that's build to met "customer" needs you can never see what the future requirements will be. Well, often you don't really know exactly what the requirements are right now :) So the best way to deal with this is to be ready for constant refactoring. If requirements are known and truly frozen (imho they rarely are though), then yes, you can think it through.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Perhaps "freezing" was the wrong term, but if you find yourself constantly changing little details in a header over a protracted period of time (the OP says "100+ times"!), then your design was insufficiently thought through for the problem at hand. Yes, even given shifting customer needs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ok, yes, I can imagine that if you need to change a little detail for the 10th time, you should have probably abstracted from this detail around the 3th-4th time, make it configurable or whatever.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329469/script-for-separating-implementation-from-headers-in-a-h-file

Also, I guess test-driven development isn't terribly popular with C++.

Comment: What's so hard about right-clicking and then selecting "Find Implementation of xxx" or the inverse - "Find Declaration of xxx"? I use this feature of Code::Blocks all the time. Make a change to one, copy it, find either the implementation (if changing the h file) or the declaration if changing the cpp file, then hit paste. Easy peasy.

Comment: @enhzflep Right. What's so hard about it? Well, if it's so easy, why can't the IDE save me 20 seconds and a disruption of my workflow and do it itself? This is not a question that describes the work experience of ALL developers. But I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one who has been bugged by this. What I wanted is hints from experienced people who have found a solution around this clearly defined problem. But such advice is, of course, impossible to get on stack overflow, which has gone the way of wikipedia in terms of shutting people out.

Comment: Some IDEs or addins do this for you. With the Visual Assist addon to Visual Studio I can either declare or define a member function then right click on it and select an option in the context menu and it will update the source or header for me. Or I can just define the function in the header and use a different context menu option to move the implementation to the source. I know Qt Creator and codeblocks have similar features.

Comment: @enhzflep: "Find Implementation" and "Find Declaration" no longer work after one has been changed.

Comment: @BenVoigt - good point, I'd forgotten the work-around I have for that. Do the find first, which opens the appropriate file in another tab, then make the change and Ctrl-Tab to the other file and paste the new sig.

Comment: @Hinton - fair call. I guess if it presented a problem as great to me as my understanding of the one it presents to you, I'd make the change to the IDE myself, or just write a plugin for it. C::B is open-source, all of the major IDEs have documented methods for plugin creation. Which IDE do you use? I'm quite prepared to have a closer look into the matter after I've slept. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [LZZ](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/) which generates header and source files from single .lzz file. Downside of using it that it not always plays nicely with IDE. For example in my case with Visual Studio + Visual Assist - you could setup syntax highlighting, debug is also working properly and walks in lzz source (but you couldn't walk or set breakpoint in generated .h/.cpp files), but when you looking for declaration you often find it in .h file instead of .lzz. I personally prefer to live without lzz and use IDE for refactoring and quick jumps between declarations and definitions, but some people do not want to wait for c++14 modules and use lzz.